# Generate a form directly with the results of a request

Tags: django, forms

I want to pass a form and the result of a request to the template of this kind when displaying, I get a form with the values ​​from the result of the query. Exactly like when you modify a tuple via the admin page of django. How to do it ?
Views.py

```
def modification_ue(request, code):
     ue_form = UEForms()
     ue      = UE.objects.get(code_ue=code)
     return render(request, 'felyn/modifier.html', {'ue_form': ue_form, 'ue': ue})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model instance `ue` can be passed to an instance of a ModelForm to have it pre-filled with values from it.

For example,

```py
ue = UE.objects.get(code_ue=code)
ue_form = UEForms(instance=ue)
return render(request, 'felyn/modifier.html', {'ue_form': ue_form, 'ue': ue})
```

Where `UEForms` isn't a ModelForm but a subclass of [`django.forms.Form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form), you need to bind the data different by passing it as a dictionary.

For example,

```py
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
#...
ue = UE.objects.get(code_ue=code)
ue_dct = model_to_dict(ue)
ue_form = UEForms(ue_dct)
return render(request, 'felyn/modifier.html', {'ue_form': ue_form, 'ue': ue})
```

However, I recommend to take advantage of [Django ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#module-django.forms.models) or the [modelform_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function) where there is minimal customization to be made in your form to link your model instance to your form.

Comment: Which is better, example 1 or example 2 ?

Comment: I find Example 1 to be better as you take advantage of implicit data binding by using ModelForm